# I'm having problems with the storage girl in act 2 in Dead Island

Tags: xbox-360, dead-island

I can give her my weapons easily but when I try to take them back and click on them they disappear and are gone for good. Is this a glitch, has anyone had the same problem? Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: How many items are in your inventory, and what's your capacity? (You should see at the top: it'll say something like Inventory 11/12.) You normally can't take an item from Jin when your inventory is full, but there could be exceptions. Also, is this on the PC or on a console? There may be ways to get around this on a PC that you couldn't do on a console. (I have the 360 version, so I don't know what's possible for the PC.)

Comment: Hey Dave, it could be that my inventory is full when I try to take it but surely that shouldn't make the item disappear you think? It's the xbox version.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. In my experience, when my inventory was full, I simply couldn't take the item ... but as you've seen before, when you complete a quest and the reward is an item, but your inventory is full, you'll drop the item. (Same thing if you make a Deo-Bomb or get someone to make you a Molotov.) So if you don't notice this, and you leave the area, the weapon would probably be gone ... but I've never had that happen with Jin.

Comment: yes I've experienced that before items dropping but Jin's just disappear, must be a glitch :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, your suspicion may be correct. The Dead Island wiki [lists this as a glitch](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Glitches#Disappearing_inventory_items) - the emphasis is mine:

> After killing a zombie by throwing a weapon at it then retrieving it, reloading a checkpoint, dying and respawning, completing an objective, or giving items to Jin to store (taking a weapon out of storage, or traveling to a new area with weapons in her inventory), a weapon(s) might spontaneously delete from the inventory it is located in. **Full Inventory's will not drop items from Jin, but delete the item(their are some cases when the item will drop to the floor)**.

The Xbox forums have a [similar post](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_360_games/a_d/f/2135/p/84004/596525.aspx#596525), as do the [GameSpot forums](http://www.gamespot.com/dead-island/forum/weapons-disappear-in-dead-island-60637347/).

But hey! There's good news! Well, sort of. In October, they [released a patch for the PC version](http://www.gamebreakers.co/news/pc/dead-island-pc-patch-fixes-save-problems-and-more/) that fixed this issue among others:

> Fixed: disappearing items when there is no place in inventory and a player tries to get an item from Jin’s storage

Unfortunately, the update for the 360 that was released in November was supposed to contain the same set of fixes, as well as other improvements (including boosting the level cap to 60) ... and it did not list a fix for the issue you describe.

I see no recent news about another patch, just about DLC, so for the time being, this is a bug, and the only workaround is to remember to check your inventory every time you interact with Jin.

Comment: Thanks very much Dave I appreciate it! Drat shame it doesn't have an update for it :(

Comment: Hey! I tried emptying my inventory before accepting stuff from jin and it worked! Thanks so much! :)

Comment: That's good to hear. Keep your eye out for news about another patch for the 360; hopefully they will fix this eventually, then I can update my answer and you won't have to worry about watching your inventory when taking stuff from Jin.